# Using port forwarding to log into remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, ssh, port-forwarding

I would like to import a local file into my remote `mysql` database, which is residing on `ec2`. How would I accomplish the following:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key.pem user@ip
$ mysql -u root localhost [ remote database ] < ~/dump.sql [ local file ]
```

Is there a way to do this with `-L`? How would I do this with one command here?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat ~/dump.sql | ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key.pem user@ip mysql -u root [ remote database ]
```